# Binding event handler to the click event using jQuery on() wouldn't work on future elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

i am trying to attach an event handler for a click event for future elements.
here is the code:

```
jQuery("#container").on("click", ".betslip_row .delete a", function(){
console.log(jQuery(this).data("outcomeId"));
});
```

Each time when a new bet is added to the betslip,  is gets refreshed(reloaded). That is why I chose "#container".

here is the link:

http://bit.ly/1coBBIa

1. Run the code on console
2. Add a few bets to the betslip
3. Delete them ony-by-one clicking on (x) sign

it supposed to print an "outcomeId" of each deleted bet on console. But it doesn't. Is there any mistake in this code?

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

if you run the code below on console, you can see the target element and its content wherever you click on the document, except that (x) bet delete option.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){ console.log(e.target); });
```

what is wrong with the (x) single bet delete? why wouldn't it fire an event or why I can't capture the event?

Comment: What *does* it do? Is the problem retrieving the `outcomeId` data property for the object (it's writing undefined to the console) or is the code not executing at all?

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question itself. My best guess at this point is that you are setting the `data` on the `.betslip_row`, but `this` in your handler is the `a`.

Comment: <a> has "data-outcome-id" attribute

Answer (score 0):

To cater for a dynamic element's click you could do the following:

```
        $(document).on('click', 'div.future-element-class-name', function () {
            // print object to console
            console.log($(this));
        });
```

Comment: this wouldn't work. 'div.future-element-class-name' either wouldn't fire an event or can't capture the fired event.

if you run the code below on console, you can see the target element and its content wherever you click on the document, except that (x) bet delete option. 

    jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    });

Comment: if you replace 'div.future-element-class-name' with the class of your x then it would work. I am using this code in my production environment and it works quite well for any elements that does not belong to the DOM. ie: dynamically added code from a partial view for example.